# Probability of a random key working

Tags: probability

So I am trying to figure out the probability of a random key working in a lock. For this example it is a 6 Pin Schlage lock that is master keyed. So for each of the 6 chambers there are 9 options. Here is where it gets complicated, each of the chambers has 2 options that work, cause its master keyed. But here is where it gets even more complicated, if two chambers are next to each other, there can't be a difference of 9, so if in chamber 1 you had a 0 you couldn't have a 9 in chamber 2. Im just trying to find this probability for a extra credit project of mine.

How would I go about this...

also order matters.

Thanks

Comment: $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ represent ten distinct values

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Perhaps you could start by computing the number of cases without restrictions and then subtract the "forbidden" ones.